# how to fix ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT importing @lens-protocol/wagmi?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

importing @lens-protocol/wagmi on next.js raises the following error:

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/......./node_modules/@apollo/client/link/context' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/....../node_modules/@lens-protocol/api-bindings/dist/index.js
> Did you mean to import @apollo/client/link/context/context.cjs?
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
> at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:412:17)
> at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:932:10)
> at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1044:11)
> at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:422:30)
> at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:222:40)
> at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
> at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
> code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
> url: 'file:///Users/sebastianserrano/projects/rpsocial/node_modules/@apollo/client/link/context',
> page: '/'
> }

Answer (score 0):

Add to next.config.js the option:
transpilePackages: ['@lens-protocol'],

Until the @apollo-client fixes the ESM modules support (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/287)

Comment: found at https://github.com/lens-protocol/lens-sdk/blob/main/examples/nextjs/next.config.js